# setTimeout delay an action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a window when i click the update button, this window should stay for 3 sec and after that close automatically end perform the update action. This is my code but it doesn't work

```
my $cScript = qq{

\$(document).ready(function(){
    var w;
    function closeWindow(){ 
        setTimeout(function() {
           w.close();
        }, 3000);
    }

    function createWindow(){
        //create the popup window.

        w=window.open("","",'width=200,height=100');

        // put something into the popup window
        try{
            w.document.write('<html><head></head><body><p>Updating...</p></body> <html>')
        }catch(err){
            //handle error here
        }
        closeWindow();

    });
};

print $q->script($cScript);
 }
```

The HTML form:

```
 $cInput_form .= $q->image_button({
      -src =>  '/media/images/save_1.png',
      -class=>'btn btn-primary btn-large',
      -title => 'update', 
      -name => 'Update', 
      -value => $row_id,
      -onclick => "createWindow()"
});



print $q->fieldset ({-class => "ui-widget ui-widget-content"}, $cInput_form);
```

where is the problem?

Comment: My guess is that the `w` variable is out of scope by the time it gets run. Are there any error messages in console?

Comment: Define "doesn't work", what is the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: In terms of philosophy, why do you wish to dictate the function of somebodies computer?

Comment: no there is no error message.

Comment: "doesn't work" = is the same as this piece of code isn't there. Doesn't perform the action i want

Comment: @Armida - I am not mystic Meg and therefore unable to ascertain the action that is required. Perhaps the code is supposed to make coffee at 10:32, black with two sugars. I dunno

Comment: I want to display a window when i click the update button, this window should stay for 3 sec and after that close automatically end perform the update action.--you can read my question i have explained there ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DEMO: *[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JAhp7/1/)***

**JS:**

```
var w;

createWindow();

function closeWindow() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        w.close();
    }, 3000);
}

function createWindow() {
    //create the popup window.
    var htmlText = "<p>Updating...</p>";
    w = window.open("", "", 'width=200,height=100');
    $(w.document.body).html(htmlText);
    closeWindow();
};
```

Comment: but i want it this way: when click the update button to open the window and after 3 sec this window should be closed automaticlly and the update action to be performed. Please could you tell me where i am wrong with my code. i am using perl

Comment: Thanks for fixing it, it is much better now :)

Comment: Thanks , but it still doesn't works. May the problem be in -onclick => "createWindow()"? i really can't see any problem and console doesn't shows any error.

Comment: that would likely be the issue, since the above works.  I've never seen the syntax you are using, I'd just bind the the button `on("click", function() { \\code })`.  Let me know if you need more specifics.

Comment: now it works but i dont want it do display the window when i go to update page i want it to display that window when click the button 'update'..what should i change?

Comment: I am calling `createWindow()` immediately, just remove that line and then bind to the on click event in jQuery for the element you want it to popup on.

Comment: i tried but doesn't work .. i cant understand now where may be the problem

Comment: $cInput_form .= $q->image_button({-src =>  '/media/images/save_1.png',-class=>'btn btn-primary btn-large',-title => 'update', -name => 'Update', -value => $row_id,-onclick => "createWindow();"});

Comment: i dont put it in jQuery but directly in html form. Is this wrong?

Comment: that is definitely a jQuery html form :) i'd just make the form an html form and then make bind the events with jQuery